# http client with custom params

Tags: ruby, stub

I use this code to make network request:

```
request = HTTPClient.new()
request.ssl_config.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
request.set_auth(url, terminal['api_login'], terminal['api_password'])        
response = request.post(url, request_body, {"Content-Type" => "application/xml", "cache-control" => "no-cache"}).body
```

But when I tried to implement rspec with stub request two params are added which are every time different on every test env:

```
stub_request(:post, "http://www.example.com/").
         with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Cache-Control'=>'no-cache', 'Content-Type'=>'application/xml', 'Date'=>'Thu, 08 Mar 2018 14:20:55 GMT', 'User-Agent'=>'HTTPClient/1.0 (2.8.3, ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13))'}).
         to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

How I can configure http client not to send `Date` and for `User-Agent` to send something simple like 'Ruby'?

Is it possible to configure these params?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great gem to deal with this kind of situations, it's called `Timecop` https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop. Basically, you can freeze time, or move to a specific date. In your case, I think you just need to freeze the time so you can set an arbitrary date in the stub headers.

```
Timecop.freeze
  stub_request(:post, "http://www.example.com/").
     with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Cache-Control'=>'no-cache', 'Content-Type'=>'application/xml', 'Date'=> Time.now, 'User-Agent'=>'HTTPClient/1.0 (2.8.3, ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13))'}).
     to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
  # the rest of your test here
end
```

Also, you can simplify your stub by omitting the headers and using a regex for the url, something like:

```
stub_request(:post, /.example.*\/).and_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```